# How to Set Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling to CollectionReusableView and CollectionVeiwCell respectively

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

UICollectionView's ContentView have two items.

- CollectionReusableView.
- CollectionViewCell.

here, I want  to set CollectionReusableView as header with Vertical Scrolling direction and collectionVeiwCells with Horitontal Scrolling Direction.

how do i make this posible

[image]

here,Top View is collectionReusableView and Bellow view is collectionViewCell.
i would like to have horizontal scrolling for CollectionveiwCells alone.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't set horizontal and vertical scrolling separately for UICollectionView's cells or collectionReusableViews. It's only possible to set scrolling directions and bounce to UICollectionView class alone.

I have planed to customize UIView with stretch header, for that i have arranged two separate UITableViews with **vertical** **scrolling** inside the two collectionViewCells with **horizontal** **scrolling** direction respectively. This collectionveiw should be part of UITableViewController with static cells which should have vertical scrolling only. To get more clarity on this please refere the image bellow.
[image]

[image]